# CircleCI CLI Error on Ubuntu WSL: open .circleci/config.yml: no such file or directory

Tags: circleci, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get the CircleCI CLI tool ( https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-jobs/ ) working on Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10.  It appeared to install successfully -- and the file permissions appear to be correct. I have Docker for Windows installed and running, and the Linux Docker client works without issue.

But now it always errors when trying to validate a CircleCI config file.

I have tried:

```
circleci config validate -c .circleci/config.yml
```

and

```
circleci config validate
```

from the root of my repo.

But each time, it gives the error:

`Error: open .circleci/config.yml: no such file or directory`

Has anyone been able to get this work?

Comment: Is it worth spinning up a Linux VM to see if the console tool works there?

Comment: I'm almost certain it will work there, so I haven't tried that.

Comment: Fair enough. That might be a good stop-gap if the problem is blocking your work. It may be worth pinging this to the CircleCI forum and/or your account manager (depending on whether you use the free or paid tier).

Answer (score -1):

`sudo` worked for me to overcome this. However, I stuck with the next error.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: You're right but I don't have the reputation to comment.